# How can i defined extra_hosts: "host.docker.internal:host-gateway" in the github workflow

Tags: docker, docker-compose, github-actions

I am creating the below workflow that should have `extra_hosts: "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"`parameter.

test.yml

```
#This workflow runs the tests in the test projects to make sure the generator works as a library where it is a Node dependency along with the template.
name: Test using test project

on:
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, reopened, synchronize, ready_for_review]

jobs:
  test:
    if: github.event.pull_request.draft == false
    name: Test generator as dependency with Node ${{ matrix.node }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    services:
      verdaccio:
        image: verdaccio/verdaccio:5
        ports:
          - '4873:4873'
        extra_hosts:
          - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
        volumes:
          - './verdaccio:/verdaccio/conf'
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node: [ '12', '14', '16', '18' ]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Run test
        run: NODE_IMAGE_TAG=${{ matrix.node }} docker-compose up --abort-on-container-exit --remove-orphans
        working-directory: ./test/test-project
```

but i am getting an error due this parameter in the workflow. How can i used it [image]https://github.com/AayushSaini101/Checking/actions/runs/7544433004

Comment: GitHub Actions [`services`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idservices) do not support this. You can write your own `docker-compose.yml` and configure `extra_hosts` according to your use case.